# How to return array of objects that are 6 hours old

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to get data that is inserted into database only 6 hours ago.

The following line is my attempt, but will return the data for 1 day:

`var todaysVotes = _votes.Where(x => x.Created >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).ToList();`

How can I filter through the list so I can get data that has been inserted 6 hours ago?

Thank you!

```
var todaysVotes = _votes.Where(x => x.Created >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)).ToList();
```

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6)

Comment: it cleary shows that you did not try anything at all, it's a very very simple problem.

Comment: Or even `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-0.25)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-6)`